# Configuration Injection null in .Net 6 Blazor Server Project

Tags: dependency-injection, configuration, blazor-server-side

I'm new to Blazor and .Net Core, and trying to figure out what I'm missing. My appsettings.Development.json looks like this:

```
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "RestServicesSettings": {
    "Url": "http://myurl.whatever",
    "UserName": "myusername",
    "Password": "mypassword"
  }
}
```

When I run my application locally I can see that it picks up the configuration as one of the sources when I look at builder.Configuration in Program.cs - it's one of the options under IConfigurationRoot.Providers and if I expand the non-public members I can see the data from the file.

On my Index.razor page I have added the following lines:

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration MyConfiguration
```

However, when I debug the app, the field MyConfiguration is null. It never becomes non-null even if I let the app completely load (I did note that it hits the breakpoint I have set twice, which I understand is expected behavior when Blazor server apps load).

I thought that everything was supposed to be wired up automatically so I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'm basing this off of the default template from generating a new Blazor server app.

I did add the following debug code to Program.cs:

```
var x = app.Configuration.GetSection("RestServicesSettings");
```

When I run the app, the value of app.Configuration is what I expect, and I see the contents of the config file through one of the non-public members, but the variable x is an empty object.

I thought I was following exactly the steps needed for config DI but something seems to be missing. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Below is the entire Razor component. The block within the `MyConfiguration != null` check is never reached.

```
@page "/"

@using MyAppNamespace.Data
@using MyAppNamespace.Services.Common
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration MyConfiguration

<PageTitle>My Title</PageTitle>

<h1>Welcome Banner Text</h1>

Descriptive text

<br />

<EditForm Model="@loginRequest">
    <div>
        <b>Log In</b>
        <InputText DisplayName="UserName" @bind-Value="@loginRequest.UserName" id="UserName" />
        <br />
        <InputText DisplayName="Password" @bind-Value="@loginRequest.Password" id="Password" />
        <br />
        <button @onclick="PerformLogOn" value="Sign On" />
    </div>

</EditForm>

@code {

    private UserLogin loginRequest = new();
    private RestServicesOptions restServiceConfiguration = new();



    public Index()
    {

        if (MyConfiguration != null) {

            MyConfiguration.GetSection(RestServicesOptions.Setting)
            .Bind(restServiceConfiguration);

            Console.WriteLine(restServiceConfiguration.Url);
        }

    }

    private void PerformLogOn()
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginRequest.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(loginRequest.Password))
        {
            
        } else
        {
            // Not provided
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using MyAppNamespace.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddOptions();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.MapBlazorHub();

app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

var x = app.Configuration.GetSection("RestServicesSettings");

app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you post the razor component that is using MyConfiguration?

Comment: @BenSampica I edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public Index()
    {

        if (MyConfiguration != null) {

            MyConfiguration.GetSection(RestServicesOptions.Setting)
            .Bind(restServiceConfiguration);

            Console.WriteLine(restServiceConfiguration.Url);
        }

    }
```

Constructor injection doesn't work this way in Blazor components. You should be using `OnInitialized{Async}` or `OnParametersSet{Async}` which are during the [component lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-6.0). It's worth noting that aside from blazor components, dependency injection works normally in C# files as you may be used to (via constructor).

```
public override void OnInitialized()
{

    if (MyConfiguration != null) {

        MyConfiguration.GetSection(RestServicesOptions.Setting)
        .Bind(restServiceConfiguration);

        Console.WriteLine(restServiceConfiguration.Url);
    }

}
```

As an recommendation, it would be better to do `.Bind()` during the service container being built and simply injecting `IOptions<RestServicesOptions>`.

Comment: Thanks @ben-sampica, I was able to make it work using OnParametersSet{Async}.

Right now this is just quick and dirty POC stuff, but if we go full bore with it I do intend to look at binding the IOptions during the build of the service container. This is something that will be needed on just about every page in the app.